# Does "View Tableau CRM on Experience Cloud pages" permission consumes a Tableau CRM license?

Tags: partner-communities, experience-cloud, tableau-crm

The permission "View Tableau CRM on Experience Cloud pages" is mentioned in this article [Enable Tableau CRM for Experience Cloud Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_setup_communities_enable.htm&type=5)

We have created a permission set that contains **only** the permission "View Tableau CRM on Experience Cloud pages" and assigned this permission set to Experience cloud users so that they can access Tableau CRM data.

**Question**: if the community user **does not** have any **Tableau CRM permission set license**, does a custom permission set with **"View Tableau CRM on Experience Cloud pages"** permission alone, consumes a Tableau CRM license ?

Most probably the answer is No, but we are still waiting for a clear confirmation about this.

Not sure if org company information reflect this.

**Additional Info**:
We do not need to embed Tableau CRM dashboard within Experience cloud pages.
Our purpose is [executing Tableau CRM query via Tableau CRM API Resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_analytics_execute_query) in LWC to render summarized data for community users in Experience cloud.

Comment: @swetha Do you have any info about this ?

Comment: For one, you need both Permission Set License and a Permission Set. Your question and the PS/PSL combination are covered in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_app_communities.htm&type=5

Comment: @identigral Thanks for the documentation. see updated question; we only need to access TCRM REST API from community, so in this case the user permission is sufficient, so TCRM license is not being used up, right ?

Comment: Running a query via API is certainly not free, it'll count against your Tableau license. To avoid that, you need to wrap the query into something that can be consumed by Site-licensed users out of the box. See the Help doc linked above for what this "something" can be.

Comment: @identigral To note that we DO have Tableau license for some users. do you have any supporting documentation stating that query via API count against your Tableau license" ? Refer to answer received from salesforce support, which confirms that the permission alone "View Tableau CRM on Experience Cloud pages" does not count against Tableau license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2022-09-15**: Following preview release Winter '23 in sandbox, it was observed that the permission set licence `CRM Analytics for Communities permission set license` is **now required** for `View CRM Analytics on Experience Cloud pages` permission in a permission set. Assigning the permission set to a community user without the permission set licence issues an error.

This is also confirmed by Salesforce support, so permission set alone no longer works as was the case in Summer 22 (April 2022)

Further info [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_setup_communities_enable.htm&type=5) :

> To enable CRM Analytics for sharing in Experience Cloud sites, complete the following steps.
> From Setup, enter Analytics in the Quick Find box, then select Settings. Select Share Analytics with Communities.
> **In Setup, assign your community members the CRM Analytics for Communities permission set license.**
> In Setup, create a permission set that includes the View CRM Analytics on Experience Cloud pages permission and assign it to your community members.

**Findings 2022-04-22**:

Information received from SF Support :

a. License will be consumed only if 'user' is assigned a 'permission set license'

b. If the permission set does not have any 'license type'. it will not consume any license

c. To track what licenses are consumed by a user, you can query on this entity filtering on Assignee=userid

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetlicenseassign.htm

Comment: Does your direct query work with this setup where there's a PS but not a PSL? It shouldn't but perhaps there's a loophole.

Comment: Yes, the query works with the PS only and returns expected results

Comment: Don't think there's a loophole. this works most probably in conjunction with the global TCRM settings "Grant all users access to Wave API" https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_setup_rest_api_enable.htm&type=5